# Render HTML string in email body with ActionMailer class in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, render, actionmailer

I'm trying to send mail in ROR using ActionMailer class.

I have created a mail object like :

```
mail(to: 'xyz@gmail.com', subject: "some subject text", body: template)
```

**Here template is a string which contains the HTML to be rendered in the mail body.**

When I'm trying the above declaration, the HTML string is getting displayed as it is in Gmail or any other client rather then getting rendered.

I'm aware of the fact that I can make a separate ERB file for view and 
mailer views are located in the app/views/name_of_mailer_class
directory.

But I want to the render the HTML string I'm generating from another source inline without storing it in a file.

I have also tried this method I found in the link below, but it is producing the same result. http://carols10cents.github.io/versioned_rails_guides/v3.2.2/action_mailer_basics.html

```
mail(:to => user.email,
         :subject => "Welcome to My Awesome Site") do |format|
      format.html { render 'another_template' }
      format.text { render :text => 'Render text' }
    end
```

Comment: Just add `content_type: 'text/html'` to `mail`

Answer (score 9):

Finally found a way to render HTML without any views file. Making the HTML string html_safe rendered the HTML in email clients.

```
mail(to: 'xyz@gmail.com', subject: 'some subject text') do |format| format.html { render html: template.to_s.html_safe }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
@template = template.html_safe
mail(to: 'xyz@gmail.com', subject: "some subject text")
```

And in your ActionMailer View `app/views/name_of_mailer_class` just render your string as

```
<%= @template %>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This would require me to make a separate file in the views folder. I was looking for a way to render the template without any make any extra file.